# Local development cycle with `cdk synth`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm using AWS CDK for IaC of a medium-size serverless application. It has multiple Python Lambdas, SQS Queues, SNS Notifications and a few more resources. Some of the Lambdas are ZIP-based and some are Docker-based.

In my development cycle of Lambdas, I'm using SAM to try out code as I write it. To do this, I usually use `aws sam invoke` calls or `aws sam start-lambda` + `aws lambda invoke` calls on the localhost endpoint that gets sets up. This is al fine, but in order for code to update I'm having to run `cdk synth` after every change to code.

I have two questions regarding this cycle and `cdk synth` specifically:

1. Is there a way to avoid having to run `cdk synth` for each code change? I noticed that `aws sam start-api` offers a "hot-reload" functionality, but it seems to only set up Lambdas that have their own endpoints in the Stack. Hot-reloading for simple, ZIP-packaged Lambdas after tiny code changes would really make a huge difference.
2. Even if it is necessary to run a `cdk synth` after each code update, even the smallest update to the code of one of the ZIP-packaged Python Lambdas triggers an entire new build of the corresponding asset where all dependencies get downloaded and installed again. The newly built asset then gets *added* to `cdk.out` rather than updating the existing asset. Is there a way to have `cdk synth` just update the changed code in the existing asset in `cdk.out`? This would both significantly increase the speed of the `cdk synth` run and my development cycle, and also avoid making `cdk.out` ever-growing in size.
3. Even if point 2 is not possible per se, is there a way to have CDK create and use a pip cache for the ZIP-based Python Lambdas? I always see this printed out when synthesizing: `WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory.`

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid that out of the box, the answer to all three is "no".

Comment: @ballcue were you able to find any workarounds for this? I'm struggling with this right now and cannot figure out the right way to do local developments especially for a case with lambdas and api getaways. Serverless frameworks provides serverless-offline where I just run `sls offline` and endpoints do "live reloading" for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `cdk deploy --hotswap`

example for seeing it in action https://cdkworkshop.com/30-python/30-hello-cdk/300-cdk-watch.html

> Note that this command should be used during development only and all production deployments should be done using the cdk deploy command (without the hotswap flag).
> This will attempt to perform a faster, short-circuit deployment if possible (for example, if you only changed the code of a Lambda function in your CDK app), skipping CloudFormation, and updating the affected resources directly. If your changes cannot be hotswapped, a full CloudFormation deployment will be performed (which will take longer, but will be more reliable).

Comment: The different options for development with `cdk deploy` like `--hotswap` are good for working with a dev environment deployed to AWS, but I was looking to improve my _local_ development and testing cycle.